# Where can I find the shortcuts contained in the start menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

The start menu in Windows 10 is essentially a bunch of shortcuts. Does anyone know if those shortcuts are all stored in an accessible folder, and if so, where that folder is?

Comment: You're referring to the WinX menu. You can find the shortcuts in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX`, but they don't behave like normal shortcuts. I've used [Win+X Menu Editor](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.30) on Windows 8, but I haven't tried it on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I just right clicked on a shortcut in the Start Menu and chose Open File Location. The location of all the shortcuts is `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. This is the folder I'm directed to from **All apps** as well as the **Most used** list.

The tiles are for Windows Store Apps which are stored in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`.

Comment: I found that folder earlier when I was searching through my computer, but what I'm really interested in are the groups of shortcuts or whatever they're supposed to be called on the right of the start menu in Windows 10; the groups have names like "life at a glance" and "play and explore". When I right click on those, I don't get an "open file location" option, only  "turn live tile off".

Comment: The Windows Store Apps are stored in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`, which you need to modify permissions to view. I'm not sure about the groups themselves.

Comment: How do I give myself permission to read the WindowsApps folder? I went to advanced security settings but the "add" button under permissions is disabled.

Comment: Nevermind, I googled it and found how-- http://caioproiete.net/en/get-access-to-the-programfileswindowsapps-folder-and-view-apps-source-code/